# Move data onto blank row below Excel from multiple columns with VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have data in the following format:

```
Name 1 | Email 1 | ID 1 | Address 1 Street | Address 1 Suburb | Address 1 City | Address 2 Street | Address 2 Suburb | Address 2 City | Address 3 Street | Address 3 Suburb | Address 3 City
<NEW LINE>
Name 2 | Email 2 | ID 2 | Address 1 Street | Address 1 Suburb | Address 1 City | Address 2 Street | Address 2 Suburb | Address 2 City
```

etc.

And I need it to look like the following:

```
Name 1 | Email 1 | ID 1 | Address 1 Street | Address 1 Suburb | Address 1 City
<NEW LINE>
Name 1 | Email 1 | ID 1 | Address 2 Street | Address 2 Suburb | Address 2 City
<NEW LINE>
Name 1 | Email 1 | ID 1 | Address 3 Street | Address 3 Suburb | Address 3 City
<NEW LINE>
Name 2 | Email 2 | ID 2 | Address 1 Street | Address 1 Suburb | Address 1 City
<NEW LINE>
Name 2 | Email 2 | ID 2 | Address 2 Street | Address 2 Suburb | Address 2 City
```

etc.

What I have so far in my spreadsheet is in column A is a COUNTA formula to work out the number of rows we need to insert below each row to allow for the data to be duplicated which is calculating fine.  From this I have used the following code to insert these number of lines which is also working fine.

```
Sub ProcessAddressLabels()
For N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(N, 1) <> "" And Cells(N, 1) <> 1 Then
            Rows(N + 1 & ":" & N + Cells(N, 1) - 1).Insert
            NumValues = Cells(N, 1)
    End If
Next N
End Sub
```

What I am not sure from here is how to copy each set of 3 cells from the end and place it along with the duplicated user data onto the lines below!

Any help is much appreciated and I hope I explained this simply enough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub Test()

   Dim rw As Range, n As Long, i As Long, x As Long

   Set rw = ActiveSheet.Rows(1) 'starting row

   Do While rw.Cells(1).Value <> ""
        'how many sets of addresses to move?
        x = Application.Ceiling((Application.CountA(rw) - 6) / 3, 1)
        If x > 0 Then
            'insert required rows
            rw.Offset(1, 0).Resize(x).Insert
            For i = 1 To x
                'copy common cells
                rw.Cells(1).Resize(1, 3).Copy rw.Cells(1).Offset(i, 0)
                'cut each address block
                rw.Cells(7 + ((i - 1) * 3)).Resize(1, 3).Cut rw.Cells(1).Offset(i, 3)
            Next i
        End If
        'move to next "new" row
        Set rw = rw.Offset(1 + x, 0)
   Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: That is pretty much perfect!  Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say I fully understood all your needs, however
would something like this help:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ActiveSheet
' copy the range C1:F1 to the start of the third row.
sht.range("C1:F1").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").range("A3")
```

Comment: I think its a start on solving it, essentially within the if statement i think it needs to do a while loop that goes through and says while value at cell n is greater than one, select the last 3 cells from this row and paste it in the blank row below along with the name data and repeat until only 1 address is left

Comment: This may be a bit more generic:     sht.range(sht.Cells(N, iFromCol), sht.Cells(N, iToCol)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(N + x, "A")